# Changing Chrome extension visibility once it's reviewed

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Does someone know if it's an instant visibility change (for example from "Private" to "Unlisted") that I can do on my developer dashboard once the extension has been successfully reviewed?
Or would a visibility change require another review submission?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any change to visibility settings will require another review.